# How to distinguish a mvc 5 response from an web api 2 response?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-web-api, owin

my situation is this: 
I'm working with mvc5 and webapi2 inside the same project. I started working with mvc, and as i needed authentication and authorization features i decided to use identity. Then, because of the changing requirements, i needed to implement a web service, so i decided to use webapi2, but it had to be authenticated as well, so i picked basic authorization as my authentication method. For this i used a custom authentication filter. Everytime something goes wrong ("no credentials", "invalid credentials") this filter return an unauthorizedResult result through the context result property:

```
context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult(new AuthenticationHeaderValue[] { new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic") }, context.Request);
```

This actually send a 401 status code through the response (i checked it using the debugger). The problem is that in my client i'm receiving a 200 status code. i figured that this is because i'm receiving the login page as a result, and all because of this block of code, that i set when i started to configured my mvc app:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Cuenta/Login"),
});
```

somehow, in some context pipeline, my unauthorized webapi response is catched and treated as response that comes from a mvc controller. So please, how i avoid this? I need to receive a 401 status code when my web service try to get a secured resource, but i still need the "return to login if secured" funcionality for my secured resources in the mvc part of my app.

Sorry i'm new at this and also sorry for my writting. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If and only if your web-api routes and not your MVC contain `/api/` you can solve it by creating your custom `CookieAuthenticationOptions.Provider.OnApplyRedirect` like this:

```
var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);
var provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider();
var originalHandler = provider.OnApplyRedirect;

provider.OnApplyRedirect = context =>
{
    if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("/api/"))
    {
        var routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary();
        var uri = new Uri(context.RedirectUri);
        var returnUrl = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query)[context.Options.ReturnUrlParameter];
        routeValues.Add(context.Options.ReturnUrlParameter, returnUrl);
        per.Action("login", "account", routeValues);
        context.RedirectUri = newUri;
        originalHandler.Invoke(context);
    }
};

app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString(urlHelper.Action("Login", "Account")),
    Provider = provider
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm gonna check this alternative, seems more appropriated that the temp solution that im using right now. what i did was to start my webapi service using `app.useWebApi(config)` in my owin startup class before set the `app.userCookieAuthentication...` block.